# How to delete Users with name but without phone and email

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete in mysql database, users with name and wihout phone and email. 
I got the select code. But I don't know how delete those results!

```
SELECT user.id FROM user, 
(SELECT emails.id
FROM
(SELECT user.id FROM email, user
    WHERE    
    email.user_id <> user.id) emails
INNER JOIN
(   SELECT user.id FROM phone, user
    WHERE    
    phone.user_id <> user.id) phones
ON emails.id = phones.id) as filter
WHERE
user.id = filter.id AND
user.name IS NOT NULL
```

If I put this:

```
DELETE FROM user
WHERE id IN
(SELECT user.id FROM user, 
(SELECT emails.id
FROM
(SELECT user.id FROM email, user
    WHERE    
    email.user_id <> user.id) emails
INNER JOIN
(   SELECT user.id FROM phone, user
    WHERE    
    phone.user_id <> user.id) phones
ON emails.id = phones.id) as filter
WHERE
user.id = filter.id AND
user.name IS NOT NULL)
```

I get -> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause

Thank you very much!

Comment: `delete from user
where id in (...)`

Comment: I get this: You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Then do `delete from user where id in (select * from (...) tmp)`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'tmp'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE u
FROM `user` u
LEFT JOIN email e ON e.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN phone p ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.name IS NOT NULL
AND p.user_id IS NULL 
AND e.user_id IS NULL
```